# Calculate value based on time in MongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

**Explanation**: Need to calculate `Total_ti` based on `ti`, when we are calculating `total_ti` based on `ti` we have to take the `ts` from the first document and take the `te` from the last document, but other documents remain as it.

Input Document

```
[
  {
    "ts": "2021-09-04T12:18:41Z",
    "te": "2021-09-04T14:59:50Z",
    "td": "2021-09-04",
    "ti": 2.69
  },
  {

    "ts": "2021-09-04T15:00:00Z",
    "te": "2021-09-04T15:05:00Z",
    "td": "2021-09-04",
    "ti": 0.08
  },
  {
    "ts": "2021-09-04T15:40:00Z",
    "te": "2021-09-04T16:00:00Z",
    "td": "2021-09-04",
    "ti": 0.33
  }
 
]
```

Expected Output Document

```
[
 {
    "ts": "2021-09-04T12:18:41Z",
    "te": "2021-09-04T16:00:00Z",
    "Total_ti": 3.10
    },
  {
    "ts": "2021-09-04T12:18:41Z",
    "te": "2021-09-04T14:59:50Z",
    "td": "2021-09-04",
    "ti": 2.69
  },
  {

    "ts": "2021-09-04T15:00:00Z",
    "te": "2021-09-04T15:05:00Z",
    "td": "2021-09-04",
    "ti": 0.08
  },
  {
    "ts": "2021-09-04T15:40:00Z",
    "te": "2021-09-04T16:00:00Z",
    "td": "2021-09-04",
    "ti": 0.33
  }
 
]
```

Comment: You should be able to do that with aggregate.  Possible $reduce or $group

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      docs: {
        $push: "$$ROOT"
      },
      ts: {
        $first: "$ts"
      },
      te: {
        $last: "$te"
      },
      ti: {
        $sum: "$ti"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      docs: {
        $concatArrays: [
          [
            {
              ts: "$ts",
              te: "$te",
              ti: "$ti"
            }
          ],
          "$docs"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$docs"
  },
  
])
```

[MongoPlayGround](https://mongoplayground.net/p/YZlCu2o_yCd)

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/ADkfLgyUUbT